# Swagger conditional example

Tags: swagger

есть схема "фото транспортного средства"

```
VehiclePhoto:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
      example: "123"
    url:
      type: string
      example: "https://test/media/content/vehicles/photo_id/test.png"
    type:
      type: string
      enum:
        - personal
        - parking
```

далее эта схема используется другой схеме

```
Vehicle:
  type: object
  properties:
    personal_photos:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/VehiclePhoto"
    last_parking_photo:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/VehiclePhoto"
```

и далее это используется в ответе апи. в примере в сваггере такой json
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но такой пример не верен, тк у last_parking_photo должен быть type: parking

есть идеи как это поправить ?

Answer (score 0):

Готовый vehicle

```
Vehicle:
  type: object
  properties:
    personal_photos:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/VehiclePhoto"
    last_parking_photo:
      allOf:
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/VehiclePhoto"
        - type: object
          properties:
            type:
              example: "parking"
```